Proper way to implement @TenantId in hibernate 6 for column discriminator multitenancy
I am trying to implement column discriminator for shared database shared schema multi tenancy in spring boot hibernate 6. I read the migration guide which says I should use @TenantId on the column, and a current tenant resolver, I did that but i get error.
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: SessionFactory configured for multi-tenancy, but no tenant identifier specified

I'll appreciate any help, been on this for days. Also I am using spring data envers for auditing.
My Base class
package com.vegeel.securitycompliancetenantservice.entities;

import com.vegeel.securitycompliancetenantservice.config.TenantContext;
import com.vegeel.securitycompliancetenantservice.utils.VegeelUtilGenerator;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.hibernate.annotations.SoftDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.SoftDeleteType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TenantId;
import org.hibernate.type.TrueFalseConverter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Auditable;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(Auditable.class)
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@SoftDelete(strategy = SoftDeleteType.DELETED, converter = TrueFalseConverter.class)
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class VegeelAuditableModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)

    String publicId;

@TenantId
    String companyId;

    String companyName;

    @CreatedDate
    LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    @CreatedBy
    @Builder.Default
    String createdBy = "SYSTEM";

    Boolean dirty = Boolean.FALSE;

    Boolean approved = Boolean.FALSE;
    @LastModifiedBy
    String lastModifiedBy;

    @PrePersist
    public void generatePublicId() {
        this.publicId = VegeelUtilGenerator.generateId();
        this.companyId = TenantContext.getTenantId();
        this.companyName = TenantContext.getTenantName();
    }


}

package com.vegeel.securitycompliancetenantservice.entities.tenant;

import com.querydsl.core.annotations.QueryEntity;
import com.vegeel.securitycompliancetenantservice.entities.VegeelAuditableModel;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "tenant_document")
@Audited
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@QueryEntity
public class TenantDocument extends VegeelAuditableModel {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String documentTitle;
    private String revisionNumber;
    private String reviewer;
    private String owner;
}

package com.vegeel.securitycompliancetenantservice.config;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings;
import org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernatePropertiesCustomizer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver<String>, HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {


    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        return TenantContext.getTenantId();
    }

     @Override
     public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
         hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, this);
     }
    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }

package com.vegeel.securitycompliancetenantservice.config;

import com.vegeel.securitycompliancetenantservice.security.CurrentAuthContext;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TenantInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {


    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        String tenantId = CurrentAuthContext.getOrganizationId();
        String tenantName = CurrentAuthContext.getOrganizationName();

        if (tenantId != null) {
            TenantContext.setTenantId(tenantId);
            TenantContext.setTenantName(tenantName);
        } else {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            response.getWriter().write("Unknown Organization");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        TenantContext.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
        TenantContext.clear();

    }

}

package com.vegeel.securitycompliancetenantservice.security;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;

import java.util.Map;

public class CurrentAuthContext {
    private static Map<String, Object> extractClaim() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        return ((Jwt) principal).getClaims();
    }

    public static String getUserEmail() {
        return (String) extractClaim().get("email");
    }

    public static String getFullName() {
        return String.valueOf(extractClaim().get("name"));
    }


    public static String getOrganizationId() {
        return String.valueOf (((Map) extractClaim().get("organization")).keySet().stream().toList().get(0));
    }
    public static String getOrganizationName() {
        return String.valueOf (((Map) extractClaim().get("organization")).keySet().stream().toList().get(0));
    }

    public static boolean isVegeelStaff() {
        return getOrganizationName() == "Vegeel";
    }
}

package com.vegeel.securitycompliancetenantservice.security;

import com.vegeel.securitycompliancetenantservice.aop.LoggingRequestTimeInterceptor;
import com.vegeel.securitycompliancetenantservice.config.TenantInterceptor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

     final TenantInterceptor tenantInterceptor;
     final LoggingRequestTimeInterceptor loggingRequestTimeInterceptor;


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(tenantInterceptor);

        registry.addInterceptor(loggingRequestTimeInterceptor)
                .excludePathPatterns(VegeelSecurityConfig.SWAGGER_WHITELIST);
    }

}


but i get this error
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: SessionFactory configured for multi-tenancy, but no tenant identifier specified
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.setUpMultitenancy(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1380) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1246) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.buildEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:771) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:754) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:519) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:735) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy218.createEntityManager(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:313) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy222.getDelegate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.provider.PersistenceProvider.fromEntityManager(PersistenceProvider.java:254) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.<init>(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.envers.repository.support.EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean$RevisionRepositoryFactory.<init>(EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.java:85) ~[spring-data-envers-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.envers.repository.support.EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.createRepositoryFactory(EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.java:63) ~[spring-data-envers-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.doCreateRepositoryFactory(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.createRepositoryFactory(TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:260) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    ... 122 common frames omitted

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.vegeel</groupId>
    <artifactId>security-compliance-tenant-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>security-compliance-tenant-service</name>
    <description>security-compliance-tenant-service</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <keycloak.version>25.0.1</keycloak.version>
        <spring-addons.version>7.8.4</spring-addons.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-pulsar</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-database-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>pulsar</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency><dependency>
        <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-addons.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.750</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
            <version>8.26.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudinary-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.39.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudinary-http44</artifactId>
            <version>1.39.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.6.0.Beta1</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I was expecting to have my schemas created and hibernate routing and filtering request by the tenant id annotated column

Add your configuration on how you did setup things, also please include packages and imports in code samples.

@M.Deinum I have edited the question to include some component.

When do you get this exception? I suspect during an incoming request?

Th application did not even start. It says tom cat cannot start.
Is there another way to implement this form of multi tenancy

Please add the full stacktrace. I suspect it fails on query validation or schema creation as that would require tenant id as well. But there is no tenant and you are return null so it cannot determine what to do.

I am constrained by maximum character to share the complet stack trace

@M.Deinum your last comment provided a clue for a better troubleshooting. It appears my tenant id was null at start up (understandable), i assigned a default value there and it worked. I am not sure why it had to be looking for tenant id when the application has not started, perhaps a validation query ran. Thanks
